# Download table from remote server to local

Tags: sql-server, export, export-to-csv

I have a long list of tables (table1, table2, etc.) residing on a remote sql server.  I am running Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to access the server.  Is there a convenient way to download the tables to my local disk (in .csv or database file)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have access to the Database in your SQL Server Management Studio, you should be able to

1. Right click on the correct database
2. Select 'Tasks'
3. Select 'Export Data'

Then you can select what type of format you want it exported to. (This includes older DB versions and excel)

Note that you will need to create the target file first.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Will that export the entire database? Since the remote is a huge database. I cannot download everything. Can I choose a set of tables to download, or can I create some sort of script/macro to do that? Thanks again!

Comment: @user3437932 You can either export a specific table or view, or write a query selecting the data you want exported.